# Getting data from Auth0/facebook JSON response with Ember 2.x

Tags: json, ember.js, auth0

I have the starter seed from Auth0 set up, which works, and gives following (snippet of) json string:

```
          {
"name": "Silvio Langereis",
 "given_name": "Silvio",
 "family_name": "Langereis",
 "gender": "male",
...
```

In my main-profile.hbs, I have following preset code from Auth0 which displays corresponding items:

```
 <h3>{{profile.name}}</h3>
<h4>{{profile.nickname}}</h4>
```

Then the full json string is displayed with `profile.body`.

When I want to show `{{profile.given_name}}`, nothing shows up. I'm a bit puzzled by this. profile.name is right above it in the json and displays just fine.
Anyone has an idea what's going on here ? The idea is to fill the already acquired data in a form so that the user can complete and submit (thus making a db record) on his first-time login.

This works properly, with the textfield filled in:

```
    <div class="form-group has-feedback {{if item.isValidUserName 'has-success'}}">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gebruikersnaam*</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-1">
            {{input type="text" value=profile.name class="form-control"}}
            {{#if item.isValidUserName}}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>{{/if}}
        </div>
    </div>
```

This does not:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Voornaam*</label>
    <div class="col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-1">
        {{input type="text" value=profile.given_name class="form-control"}}
        {{#if item.isValidFirstName}}<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>{{/if}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm such a fool !

In routes/user-profile.js, the json gets parsed and added to a localstorage object 'profile'. There I have to declare which values I want to put into it.

routes/user-profile.js:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    const profile = localStorage.getItem('profile');
    const profileObject = JSON.parse(profile);
    const model = {
      name: profileObject.name,
      nickname: profileObject.nickname,
      pictureUrl: profileObject.picture,
      email: profileObject.email,
      body: profile.trim()
    };
    return model;
  }
});
```

Adding following line, fixes the problem: `given_name: profileObject.given_name,`

Rinse and repeat for the needed values.